# Xamarin Tabbed Page not showing Content

Tags: xamarin, tabbedpage

trying to learn more about Tabbed Pages with i've built a very simple App containing three content Pages with a code like this:

```
public class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Hello Page1" }
            }
        };
    }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page 1 On Appearing");
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page 1 Disappearing");
    }

}
```

The Main Page looks like this:

```
public class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        var page1 = new Page1();
        page1.Title = "Page1";
        var page2 = new Page2();
        page2.Title = "Page2";
        var page3 = new Page3();
        page3.Title = "Page3";

        Children.Add(page1);
        Children.Add(page2);
        Children.Add(page3);
    }
}
```

Now when i click on a new tab, the OnDisappearing() method of the old tab is called, as well as the OnAppearing() method of new tab, BUT the content of the new page is not shown. It remains the content of the old page. 
To show the content of the new page i have to click again on the tab.

Does anybody has experienced this kind of behaviour?

Best regards,

Marco